# <uses-configuration> and the Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

After adding

```
<uses-configuration android:reqTouchScreen="stylus"/>
```

to `AndroidManifest.xml`, the Google Play Store shows that absolutely no devices are compatible.

How do I restrict an app to be available only on devices that have a stylus?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you don't, because there are effectively no devices that can *only* be operated with a stylus. Devices like the Galaxy Note *can* be used with their supplied stylus, but can also be used with a finger.

The 
`android:reqTouchScreen="stylus"` option was added in to support devices that might use a old-style resistive touchscreen that can only be used with such a stylus. It does not refer to the modern sort of "active stylus" you see accompany some devices.

If you are using some proprietary API for interacting with the stylus (e.g., Samsung S-Pen), there may be aspects of how you connect to their API (e.g., `<uses-library>`) that will serve as a filter, restricting you to devices that support that API.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Rather than the library, can one restrict an app to be available only on those devices that know about hovering?

Comment: @Calaf: Not in general, no.